# Open Refine / Google Refine - Remove blank cells in a column

Tags: openrefine

The task is simple to understand, I have a table like this:

[image: table 1]

And I would like to edit the column "L1_latitud" to collapse (or remove) all the blank cells:

[image: table2]

It looks like a simple task but I can't find out a way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a programming question, but if what you show is a single Refine record (you can check by switching from Row mode to Record mode for viewing), you should be able to use "Join multi-valued" cells to collapse all the values into a single string with separators.  From there the split(), filter(), join() methods would allow you to filter out the empty values and put the string back together.  Finally, "Split multi-valued cells" would split them out into separate cells again.

I sense that you've already done some processing here, so there might be an easier way to do this if you started a step or two earlier in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Create "Facet" -> "Customized facets" -> "Facet by null"

[image: screenshot]

then simply exclude True choice in facet